# How to preset the focus by default on the WhatsApp entry in the share intent list

Tags: android, android-intent, share, whatsapp

I am selecting some text from a textview and I want to share it with Implicit Intent - this works fine.

However, on the `Complete action using` dialog (the one that shows which applications are available to handle the intent) I would like to default the focus to `WhatsApp` if the user has it installed.

It should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this function to share text only on whatsapp.

```
private void shareOnWhatsapp(String textToShare) {
try {
  Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

  whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textToShare);
  whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
  PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
  List<ResolveInfo> lract = pm.queryIntentActivities(whatsappIntent,
      PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
  boolean resolved = false;
  for (ResolveInfo ri : lract) {
    if (ri.activityInfo.name.contains("whatsapp")) {
      whatsappIntent.setClassName(ri.activityInfo.packageName,
          ri.activityInfo.name);
      resolved = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  startActivityForResult(
      resolved ? whatsappIntent : Intent.createChooser(
          whatsappIntent, "Choose one"), 2);
} catch (final ActivityNotFoundException e) {
  Toast.makeText(ShareRecommendationActivity.this,
      "Whatsapp not installed.",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
  }
```

Comment: Actually I don't want to share my text directly on whats app. I just want to all the apps, and get only focus by default on whats app. As you can see in the image. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding and experience it is not possible to highlight watsapp directly cause when you call share intent in application you will never have control on next list i.e. intent list so you can not get watspp as selected manner

if you want control on it i mean you want watsapp as selected color then you need to create your own custom intent list and then you can highlight it so user can click on it directly

but problem is that if suppose user dont have watspp in his phone then you need to write code for that also cause when you are going to do it custome it will take so much time but am pretty sure you can achive it if you go through custom intent list